# Increase the size of the icons in ubuntu desktop

Tags: gnome, unity, icons, launcher

I got my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS desktop icons are in normal size,

Now, It is very small, I dont know how it changes its icon size

[image]

The Icons in the left panel are very small,
But, as you can see, in the right bottom corner, the Home folder icon is in normal size. The icons in the left panel only become very small

How to increase that icon size?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the size of the icons in the dock select `Settings > Appearance > Dock` and use the slider to increase the *icon size* to what you require.

[image]

In the same menu, you can also change the size of the *Desktop Icons* as required.